# JaVers - retrieve audit changes by composite key

Tags: javers

I have a test case which tries to query Child entity changes by its instanceId, it throws an Exception:

```
@TypeName("EntityOne")
    class EntityOne {
        @Id int id
        String name
        List<EntityTwo> entityTwos

        EntityOne(int id, String name, List<EntityTwo> entityTwos) {
            this.id = id
            this.name = name
            this.entityTwos = entityTwos
        }

    }

    @TypeName("EntityTwo")
    class EntityTwo {
        @Id int id
        String name
        @Id int entityOneId

        EntityTwo(int id, String name, entityOneId) {
            this.id = id
            this.name = name
            this.entityOneId = entityOneId
        }
    }
```

These are the data audited

```
oldOne = new EntityOne(1, "EntityOne", [new EntityTwo(1, "EntityTwo",1)])
newOne = new EntityOne(1, "EntityOne", [new EntityTwo(1, "EntityTwo",1),
                                                    new EntityTwo(2, "EntityTwoOne",1)])
```

This is query throwing exception

```
 entityTwoChanges = javers.findChanges(QueryBuilder.byInstanceId(1, EntityTwo) // Error is thrown
                .withNewObjectChanges()
                .withChildValueObjects()
                .build())
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.Map
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at org.javers.core.metamodel.type.InstanceIdFactory.dehydratedLocalId(InstanceIdFactory.java:48)
    at org.javers.core.metamodel.type.InstanceIdFactory.create(InstanceIdFactory.java:22)
    at org.javers.core.metamodel.type.EntityType.createIdFromInstanceId(EntityType.java:127)
    at org.javers.core.metamodel.object.GlobalIdFactory.createInstanceId(GlobalIdFactory.java:115)
    at org.javers.core.metamodel.object.GlobalIdFactory.createFromDto(GlobalIdFactory.java:127)
    at org.javers.repository.jql.FilterDefinition$IdFilterDefinition.compile(FilterDefinition.java:27)
    at org.javers.repository.jql.JqlQuery.compile(JqlQuery.java:120)
    at org.javers.repository.jql.QueryCompiler.compile(QueryCompiler.java:16)
    at org.javers.repository.jql.ChangesQueryRunner.queryForChanges(ChangesQueryRunner.java:20)
    at org.javers.repository.jql.QueryRunner.queryForChanges(QueryRunner.java:48)
    at org.javers.core.JaversCore.findChanges(JaversCore.java:196)
    at com.example.CaseQueryByCompositeKey.should able to query audit changes by composite key(CaseQueryByCompositeKey.groovy:60)
```

and also Is there way to query by composite key in JaVers?

Answer (score 0):

It worked after passing instanceId as map:

```
entityTwoChanges = javers.findChanges(QueryBuilder.byInstanceId([id: 1, entityOneId: 1], EntityTwo)
                .withNewObjectChanges()
                .withChildValueObjects()
                .build())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's explicitly shown in the javadoc

```java
    /**
     * Query for selecting Changes, Snapshots or Shadows for a given Entity instance.
     * <br/><br/>
     *
     * For example, last Changes on "bob" Person:
     * <pre>
     * javers.findChanges( QueryBuilder.byInstanceId("bob", Person.class).build() );
     * </pre>
     *
     * @param localId Value of an Id-property. When an Entity has Composite-Id (more than one Id-property) &mdash;
     *                <code>localId</code> should be <code>Map&lt;String, Object&gt;</code> with
     *                Id-property name to value pairs.
     * @see <a href="https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/master/javers-core/src/test/groovy/org/javers/core/examples/CompositeIdExample.groovy">CompositeIdExample.groovy</a>
     */
    public static QueryBuilder byInstanceId(Object localId, Class entityClass){
        Validate.argumentsAreNotNull(localId, entityClass);
        return new QueryBuilder(new IdFilterDefinition(instanceId(localId, entityClass)));
    }
```

try to read the javadoc first, before asking questins about a method